# How to connect external files to docker-nginx container?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-volume, docker-container, docker-image

I read almost all threads under volume but I am still not able to solve my issue.

- I have a nginx image in my docker. When I do **docker images** this is what I get:

```
xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
$ docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED      SIZE
nginx        latest    ae2feff98a0c   5 days ago   133MB
```

In my current directory **desktop/website** I have a file called index.html which I want to map inside the **usr/share/nginx/html** docker container.
For that I type a command :

```
xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
$ docker run --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

The command runs fine and I get some random numbers like

```
xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
$ docker run --name website -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
29630977004cb59b3f4b67ea99f5bb28e3434c02c4c62d4cb20c4b1ccd82fafc

xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
```

But when I do localhost:8080, I get the same old message "welcome to Nginx."

I tried going inside the container(usr/share/nginx/html) to see if changes have made with the command

```
xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
$ docker exec -i website bash
```

I found nothing is changed. The files are still the same. (I don't know if it is supposed to be changed)

How to do this. Is there an alternative. I am using **git bash** and I am on windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it is an issue with git-bash that doesn't recognize ($pwd). Try using one of these ways:

```
docker run --name website -v /$PWD:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx

docker run --name website -v "$PWD":/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx

docker run --name website -v /c/some/some:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx

docker run --name website -v C:\\some\\path:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Sorry, I have no Windows here to try this out. Hope that works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might be coming late, but hopefully it could help someone else just getting into Docker
on a Windows machine, it would be

```
xxxxxx@DESKTOP-7904JF2 MINGW64 ~/desktop/website
$ docker run --name website -v ${pwd}:/usr/share/nginx/html -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

your 'pwd' should be wrapped in curly braces instead
this should be run from Powershell